# Store logs from applications in kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, storage, amazon-eks

What is the recommended approach to store the logs of applications deployed on Kubernetes? I read about ELK stack, but not sure about the pros and cons. Needs recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask specifically about storing application logs in **kubernetes cluster**, there are a few different approaches. First I would recommend you to familiarize with [this article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the official **kubernetes documentation**.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience with the Kubernetes logging, I would suggest you go with EFK stack (Fluentd/flunetbit --> Kafka --> Logstash/flunetd --> Elasticserach --> kibana), this one has initial challenges during setup but once this is up and running, it will be like a super scalable system where you don't need to worry about volume of logs you are shipping.

Another approach you can take is shipping logs directly from fluentd/fluentbit/filebeat to Elasticsearch. The drawback of this approach is if ES has some issue then you may lose your logs.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I want to emphasize the response from @javajon. There is a KataCoda exercise specifically for logging at https://katacoda.com/javajon/courses/kubernetes-observability/efk.

Logging is a very large topic with lots of variables. In order to get any specific advice, you'll need to comment about your goals for logging. Is it related to performance, compliance, security, debugging, observability or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Try to get some knowledge by yourself.
Every storage have some pros and cons according to requirement we use them.
Visit https://medium.com/volterra-io/kubernetes-storage-performance-comparison-9e993cb27271
and learn more.
I will surely somehow help.

Comment: Logstash or Fluend (ELK and EFK) is another considersation. You can experience and decompose how EFK works using this hands-on experience: [EFK tutorial](https://katacoda.com/javajon/courses/kubernetes-observability/efk)

Comment: This answer related to storage, not logging specifically.